# Reset Mac OS X Terminal to default

Tags: macos, osx-lion, terminal.app

I accidentally renamed my "Basic" terminal profile under Terminal -> Preferences -> Settings. I renamed it back but this got me wondering if there was a way to reset all terminal settings to defaults. So for example if I renamed "Basic" to "Foo" is there a command or way to reset it back to "Basic" without having to select it and rename?

Is it just a matter of deleting the .plist file in `~/Library`?

Comment: For followers, if your colors for a particular terminal "got messed up" (kids, heh), you may be able to restart Terminal app and get back to normal...without having to mess with anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Correct. Just quit Terminal.app, and make a backup of the following file, then delete it.

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist
```

Terminal will create a new, default one once you restart it. Your preferences are stored in that preference list file – a normal Dictionary.

[image]

Comment: Strangely, I cannot reset my Terminal app to the default settings. I had chosen Novel rather than Basic, and now the Terminal keeps giving me Novel. And a bug !

Comment: I heard that on OS X Mavericks, the preferences are all cached, so this might be an explanation if you're on 10.9.

Comment: Prefs cached ?? This sounds like a troubleshooting horror.

Comment: I am on Mavericks.

Comment: Deleting the Terminal preferences file is overkill and unnecessary: there is a command to restore the default profiles. See my answer: http://superuser.com/a/448679/81175

Comment: @ChrisPage You may have noticed that more than three years ago I commented on your answer and gave it a +1 ... Also, the OP asked whether it is a matter of deleting a .plist file, which it actually is.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, there’s a command to restore all the built-in settings profiles (each item in the Settings list is called a “settings profile” or “profile”):

In the Preferences window, in the Settings panel:

1. Click the action (gear) button at the bottom of the list.
2. Choose **Restore Defaults**.

This will reset modified profiles and recreate any that have been deleted or renamed. Custom profiles are left as-is. (In your specific case this means that your renamed “Basic” will remain and a new “Basic” will be created.)

[image: Restore Default Terminal Settings Profiles]

Comment: Heh, how could I miss that? :) +1

Comment: Hats off sir. I don't know either...